Need advice for generating PMTiles without changing the value of feature variables at different zoom values
I am working on the visualisation on this website:
https://morphometric-explorer-v2.netlify.app/
The website currently takes the "cluster" variable of each polygon and displays it - but while it is able to simplify and gamma out polygons to make everything fit, the cluster value keeps changing between zoom levels.
I am running the following command:
    tippecanoe -o "$output_file" "$file" -zg -pn --minimum-detail=9 --force -aD -P --increase-gamma-as-needed --preserve-input-order --order-by=cluster --no-tiny-polygon-reduction

Would anyone have any advice on how to preserve the cluster values on different zoom level? The raw GeoJSON file is 3gb, so some level of simplification and sparsification is needed.
